# How to run a program from cmd

Tags: command-line, f#, arguments, command-line-arguments

I want to be able to run it on any text file, without having to specify the path in the code. Can anybody help? Thanks

```
open System.IO
type Data() =
    member x.Read() =

        use stream = new StreamReader @"D:\Searcher.txt"


        let mutable valid = true

        printfn "Please enter the number you want to search for: "
        let mutable x = System.Console.ReadLine()

        let mutable lines = 1

        while (valid ) do
            let line = stream.ReadLine()
            if (line = null) then
                valid <- false
            else if (line = x) then
                printfn "String found: %s" x
                printfn "Found on: Line %i " lines
                valid <- false
            else
                lines <- lines + 1

let data = Data()
data.Read()

System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your goal (expected outcome)? What specific problem have you encountered?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I can only guess that you want this code to run in an executable program to which the file path (here `D:\Searcher.txt`) is passed as a command line parameter; is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three ways to pass the file name as an argument. Use `argv` in a compiled program, use `fsi.CommandLineArgs` if you are executing via fsi, and finally get the file name argument via `Console.Readline`, exactly as you get the string to search for. You don't need to define a class to do this, so I removed it and just made it a function. You can also simplify the code within you read function to be less imperative.

**Version 1**

In a compiled program `argv` is passed as a string list to main:

```
open System.IO
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let fName = argv.[0] // get the file name as the first argument

    let readData (fName:string) =

            use stream = new StreamReader(fName)
            let mutable valid = true

            printfn "Please enter the number you want to search for: "
            let mutable x = System.Console.ReadLine()

            let mutable lines = 1

            while (valid ) do
                let line = stream.ReadLine()
                if (line = null) then
                    valid <- false
                else if (line = x) then
                    printfn "String found: %s" x
                    printfn "Found on: Line %i " lines
                    valid <- false
                else
                    lines <- lines + 1


    readData fName

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

You would run this, after compiling the application, like this:

```
.\ConsoleApplication13.exe "c:\tmp\SearchText.txt"
```

**Version 2**

If you don't want to compile but just run it through fsi:

```
open System.IO
let fName = fsi.CommandLineArgs.[1] // you need the second item from the argument list, 
                                   //because the first one is the script name itself

let readData (fName:string) =

        use stream = new StreamReader(fName)
        let mutable valid = true

        printfn "Please enter the number you want to search for: "
        let mutable x = System.Console.ReadLine()

        let mutable lines = 1

        while (valid ) do
            let line = stream.ReadLine()
            if (line = null) then
                valid <- false
            else if (line = x) then
                printfn "String found: %s" x
                printfn "Found on: Line %i " lines
                valid <- false
            else
                lines <- lines + 1


readData fName

System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
0 // return an integer exit code
```

You would run this like this:
`Fsi.exe .\Script1.fsx "C:\tmp\SearchText.txt"`

For version 3 I won't spell it out because you are already using `Console.Readline` to get the search string. You can get the file name in the exact same way.

Also `x` doesn't need to be mutable.